# Free Portable Hard disk bad sector fixer software

Tags: gratis, portable, data-recovery, hard-disk

Performing bad sector check on high-capacity hard disk (e.g. 1 TB and above SATA HDD) usually consume lots of time (e.g. 120 minutes and above).

Are there free, portable hard disk bad sector fixer or/and detector software that speed up the whole process to 60 minutes and

either

- able to mark the bad sector, if data are corrupted

or

- recovering the data and place it on a good empty sector, if bad sector are detected and data is not corrupted.

Comment: Nothing will fix the bad sector, but others may be able to recommend software that will mark the sector as bad, and perhaps try to recover data from it.

Comment: I don't think such speeds are attainable without some kind of consequence, like data loss in those sectors.

Comment: One doesn't fix a broken sector. One restores data from backup. The question comes from a fundamentally flawed assumption.

Comment: This is basically how filesystems are supposed to work by default, if it can't write a sector it should mark it bad & move on during normal op's.